# getting RSSI of Bluetooth connection with hcitool, crashing

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluez

I have read through many stackoverflow posts about the possibility of getting RSSI of a Bluetooth connection.  It seems as though Android does not directly expose this through any API and that the only hope is to get straight to the bluez API.

Apparently, once you have a connection with a Bluetooth device, you can use hcitool to get the RSSI or link quality like:

```
hcitool rssi E8:06:88:2F:D1:4E
```

However, whenever I try to do this using hcitool, I am getting segmentation faults:

```
130|shell@android:/system/bin # hcitool rssi E8:06:88:2F:D1:4E
RSSI return value: 0
[1] + Stopped (signal)     hcitool rssi E8:06:88:2F:D1:4E
```

Even if I try to create a connection with hcitool, instead of the BluetoothAdapter:

```
130|shell@android:/system/bin # hcitool cc E8:06:88:2F:D1:4E
Can't create connection: I/O error
```

I'm using this version of hcitool:  http://code.google.com/p/androidobex/downloads/detail?name=hcitool

However, it says its the "Android dev phone version" and I am clearly using something newer than a G1.  But, I can't find any other version of hcitool.

Comment: Why do you need to use hcitool, as opposed to the `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI` mechanism, as described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/8qXyalWHadY

Comment: that does not allow you to get the RSSI value of a connection, it only allows you to get the RSSI of devices in discoverable mode from a scan.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the club! I have the same exact problem with the hcitool. The problem is a faulty implementation.

There is a structure allocated (cr) for each command which is later used in an ioctl() cmd. I had a look at the kernel implementation and realized the required amount of bytes is larger than the one supplied.

Since I am currently not able to patch this, I wrote myself a simple so lib, which modifies each malloc() call to allocate an additional 100 bytes as a safety margin. Then no crash happens:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t)=NULL;


void *malloc(size_t size) {
    if (!real_malloc) {
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    }

    return real_malloc(size + 100);
}
```

Use the following line to compile (or insert your cross compiler if necessary):

```
gcc memsafe.c --shared -fPIC -O2 -ldl -o libmemsafe.so
```

Then write yourself a bash script to get various values:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
    export LD_PRELOAD="libmemsafe.so"
    hcitool cc $1
    hcitool rssi $1
    hcitool lq $1
    hcitool tpl $1 0
    hcitool tpl $1 1
else
    echo "Usage: $0 <btAddr>"
fi
```

If you can compile the hcitool yourself, look for all lines like this:

```
cr = malloc(sizeof(*cr) + sizeof(struct hci_conn_info));
```

...and change them to ...

```
cr = malloc(sizeof(*cr) + sizeof(struct hci_conn_info) + 100);
```

If you care to estimate the correct size, please feel free to correct the implementation.

Hope this answer still helps or will help somebody in the future

Answer (score 1):

hcitool source is part of the bluez stack. You need Android NDK to compile it against the correct version of linux shared libraries. I have downloaded the entire android source for 4.0.4, its a huge blob, but it worked.