# Get rssi value for a device that is connected to my laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, rssi

I'm trying to find the RSSI value for a phone that is connected to my laptop by Bluetooth. I use the below command on Ubuntu:

```
hcitool rssi AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

‌‌But I get this:

RSSI return value: 0

But I want the value in the range of -20 to -100 for example.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting RSSI of Bluetooth connection with hcitool, crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752264/getting-rssi-of-bluetooth-connection-with-hcitool-crashing)

Answer (score 2):

The HCI tool doesn't retrieve data directly from your radio, rather it uses the standardized Bluetooth HCI (host-controller interface). The definition of the read RSSI HCI command, from the spec:

> 7.5.4 Read RSSI command
> Description:
> This command reads the Received Signal Strength Indication (RSSI) value
> from a Controller.
> For a BR/EDR Controller, a Connection_Handle is used as the Handle
> command parameter and return parameter. The RSSI parameter returns the
> difference between the measured Received Signal Strength Indication (RSSI)
> and the limits of the Golden Receive Power Range for a Connection_Handle to
> another BR/EDR Controller. The Connection_Handle shall be a
> Connection_Handle for an ACL connection. Any positive RSSI value returned
> by the Controller indicates how many dB the RSSI is above the upper limit, any
> negative value indicates how many dB the RSSI is below the lower limit. The
> value zero indicates that the RSSI is inside the Golden Receive Power Range.
> Note: How accurate the dB values will be depends on the Bluetooth hardware.
> The only requirements for the hardware are that the BR/EDR Controller is able
> to tell whether the RSSI is inside, above or below the Golden Device Power
> Range.
> The RSSI measurement compares the received signal power with two
> threshold levels, which define the Golden Receive Power Range. The lower
> threshold level corresponds to a received power between -56 dBm and 6 dB
> above the actual sensitivity of the receiver. The upper threshold level is 20 dB
> above the lower threshold level to an accuracy of ±6 dB.

So basically the reason you're seeing "0" is because your device is within the "golden range" as configured in the hardware driver. You will not be able to get a more accurate reading using HCI commands